# Determine when display changes (new/less screens connected, or resolution) in c#

Tags: c#, windows-7

As the title states.

I'd like to be able to tie into an event somehow that notifies my application when the screen resolution is going to change, or screens are added/removed.

Mainly I want to write an app that keeps track of where applications are running on my multiple screens, so that when I undock my laptop, and then redock it, it can reposition windows where they were, instead of stacking them all on my primary monitor.

(re: to solve this problem: https://superuser.com/questions/289908/windows-7-constantly-forgets-my-dual-monitor-setup)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DisplaySettingsChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanged.aspx) event.  The [SystemParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.aspx) class will give you limited information about the primary screen as well as the virtual screen (the bounding rectangle of all your screens; only useful for simple setups), but if you want more specific information you'll probably need to pinvoke the Win32 API.

Comment: Use the .NET Screen class.